# Recursive promise not resolving

Tags: javascript

I have a function that fetches some data. If data is not available (it becomes available after some short time), it returns null. I created a function, that returns promise, which is wrapped around logic that fetches data and checks if it is is available - if not, it calls itself:

```
Foo.prototype.fetchDataWrapper = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = fetchData();
        if (data) {
            resolve(data)
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                return this.fetchDataWrapper()
            }, 100)
        }
    })
}
```

Problem is, that despite data is fetched correctly, this promise never resolves. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your fetch method return?

Comment: I am asking the same thing :-). It is synchronous? (probably not). I mean `fetchData();`. Can you show us that function?

Comment: It returns actual data or null. It doesnt't take any arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return this.fetchDataWrapper()` is returning from the **timer callback**, no `fetchDataWrapper`. `fetchDataWrapper` has already returned. Instead, pass that promise into `resolve`:

```
Foo.prototype.fetchDataWrapper = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = fetchData();
        if (data) {
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(this.fetchDataWrapper()); // *****
            }, 100);
        }
    })
};
```

When you pass a promise to `resolve`, it makes the promise `resolves` belong to resolve **or reject** based on the promise you pass to it.

*(I've also added some missing semicolons to that code. I recommend being consistent with semicolons: Either rely on ASI or don't, both don't mix the two. Also recommend not relying on ASI, but that's a style choice.)*

---

Side note: It would probably make sense to reject after X attempts, perhaps:

```
Foo.prototype.fetchDataWrapper = function (retries = 5) {
// *** Declare retries param with default -^^^^^^^^^^^
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = fetchData();
        if (data) {
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            if (retries) { // *** Check it
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(this.fetchDataWrapper(retries - 1));
                    // *** Decrement and pass on -^^^^^^^^^^^
                }, 100);
            } else {
                reject(); // *** Reject
            }
        }
    })
};
```